# Updating Xamarin.Forms breaks Prism navigation for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

I have a Xamarin app made up of several pages, and I'm using Prism with AutoFac. I'm unable to update Xamarin.Forms without breaking navigation on the Android project only. It works fine on iOS.

I started with Xamarin.Form 3.1, and I cannot update to anything beyond that. My main page is a login page - when that is successful I navigate to the home page like so:

```
try
{
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri($"/NavigationPage/{nameof(HomePage)}", UriKind.Absolute));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Error(e);
}
```

The navigation is not throwing any exceptions, and I'm not picking up any errors anywhere. Release notes for Xamarin 3.2 doesn't provide any clues either. I don't even know if this is a Xamarin or Prism issue. A few days of debugging and I feel no closer to figuring this out.

Has anyone else experienced this? or have any idea what could be going wrong?

**Edit 1:**
I finally isolated the issue - the fix was to call BeginInvokeOnMainThread when I navigate. But a few things still don't make sense to me:

1. This should raise an exception, so I must be hiding it somewhere. Is there anything obvious in the code below [This is the first time I've used Async, so seems likely I'm doing something wrong there]?
2. Why did this work with Xamarin 3.1 on not later versions
3. My logging confirms that the original navigation code was running on the main thread, but it still failed.

The code:

We are doing client-side google authentication with Azure, if that is successful we navigate to the home page.

First step, we connect to GooglePlay and authenticate the user

```
public void Login(MobileServiceClient client, Action<string, bool> onLoginComplete)
{
    _client = client;
    _onLoginComplete = onLoginComplete;

    var signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(_googleApiClient);
        ((MainActivity)_context).StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);

    _googleApiClient.Connect();
}
```

The result comes to OnActivityResult in MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SignInId)
    {
        Log.Info("Received result from Google sign in");
        var result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        DroidLoginProvider.Instance.OnAuthCompleted(result);
    }
}
```

Which calls the OnAuthCompleted method. There are a few paths here. If the token is valid we don't re-authenticate with Azure, and just retrieve the saved user details:

```
public void OnAuthCompleted(GoogleSignInResult result)
{
    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        Log.Trace("Native google log in successful");
        var signInAccount = result.SignInAccount;

        var accounts = _accountStore.FindAccountsForService("monkey_chat");
        if (accounts != null)
        {
            foreach (var acct in accounts)
            {
                if (acct.Properties.TryGetValue("token", out var azureToken) && acct.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out var email))
                {
                    if (!IsTokenExpired(azureToken))
                    {
                        Log.Trace("Auth token is still valid");
                        _client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(acct.Username)
                        {
                            MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = azureToken
                        };

                        _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(email, true);
                        return;
                     }
                     Log.Trace("Auth token no longer valid");
                 }
             }
        }

        // Authenticate with Azure & get a new token
        var token = new JObject
        {
            ["authorization_code"] = signInAccount.ServerAuthCode,
            ["id_token"] = signInAccount.IdToken
        };

        try
        {
            var mobileUser = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.Trace("Authenticating with Azure");
                    return await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Error(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var account = new Account(_client.CurrentUser.UserId);
        account.Properties.Add("token", _client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
        account.Properties.Add("email", signInAccount.Email);
        _accountStore.Save(account, "monkey_chat");

        _googleUser = new GoogleUser
        {
            Name = signInAccount.DisplayName,
            Email = signInAccount.Email,
            Picture = new Uri((signInAccount.PhotoUrl != null
                ? $"{signInAccount.PhotoUrl}"
                : $"https://autisticdating.net/imgs/profile-placeholder.jpg")),
            UserId = SidHelper.ExtractUserId(mobileUser?.UserId),
            UserToken = mobileUser?.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken
        };

        _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(signInAccount.Email, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(string.Empty, false);
            Log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(string.Empty, false);
    }
}
```

My original OnLoginComplete[Not working]:

```
private async void OnLoginComplete(bool successful, bool isNewUser)
{
    if (successful)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info("Starting navigation to home page");
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri($"/NavigationPage/{nameof(HomePage)}",                UriKind.Absolute)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

New OnLoginComplete[Working]

```
private void OnLoginComplete(bool successful, bool isNewUser)
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
       if (successful)
       {
           try
           {
               Log.Info("Starting navigation to home page");
               _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri($"/NavigationPage/{nameof(HomePage)}",                UriKind.Absolute)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Log.Error(e);
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: When you try to update to the latest Xamarin Forms, Prism, Autofac packages, you are still seeing the issue? Could you provide minimal producible code so people can try to replicate/solve your problem

Comment: Could you provide a code sample to reproduce for us to test?

Comment: It's a pretty big app right now & I can't reproduce it when I make a dummy app.

Updating Prism doesn't help the issue

Comment: Not the whole project, just a simple code sample which could reproduce.

Comment: This doesn't provide enough information to help you. I do advise that you not use Prism.Autofac.Forms as it's no longer a supported container. We have no idea here what version of Prism you're using though. Depending on what version you're on you may need to provide an implementation of ILoggerFacade to be able to see what the exception is, if you're on a newer version of Prism you'd want to do `var result = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(...)` and check the result for an exception. There are lots of reasons you might have an issue they're all going to be in your code though...

Comment: @DanS. We using Prism 7.0, which should throw an exception if there is an error. I tried 7.1 (that's where they changed the method to return the result) and it returned navigation is successful, even though the page didn't change. I'll look into ILoggerFacade.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Is the above enough okay?

Comment: what happens if you just did `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage)`